# Annotations that work in ggplot2 3.1.1 fail in 3.2.1. How to fix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, facet-grid

My code that makes custom annotations in faceted histograms in ggplot2 3.1.1 fails on a different computer running ggplot2 3.2.1, throws this error:
*Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label*

How can I make my annotations appear in the facets made in ggplot2 3.2.1?

Minimal example using mtcars follows.

Thank you!!

```
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

lb <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
      summarize(n=n(), avg_gear=round(mean(gear),1))
lb$label <- paste0("n=",lb$n, "     avg_gear=",lb$avg_gear)
print(lb)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +
facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
annotate("text", x=4, y=13, label=lb$label) +  
ggtitle("histograms of gear, faceted by cyl")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use another layer:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(data = lb, aes(x = 4, y = 13, label = label)) +    # in place of annotate
  ggtitle("histograms of gear, faceted by cyl")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Jon Spring.

Comment: Jon, your solution does not work with my actual code.My minimal case was a bit too minimal? My actual code colors the histograms also. The following works with the 4th line commented out and no annotation, but fails when I uncomment it and try to annotate. Really appreciate any help. I'd rather not have to revert to ggplot2 3.1.1.     
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear, group=carb, fill=carb)) +    
geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +    
facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +    
geom_text(data = lb, aes(x = 4, y = 13, label = label)) +      
ggtitle("histograms of gear, faceted by cyl,colored by carb")

Comment: Does `lb` have carb column? If not, you might want to move that part of the `aes()` out of the global call upfront and into the geom_histogram layer.

Comment: That technique works in my production code. Thank you again.